# What kind of problems might result from unquoted lifted constructors?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-warnings, data-kinds

I am using the GHC extension `-XDataKinds` and have `-Wall` turned on in a Haskell library I am writing. I am getting a warning about using unticked promoted constructors because `-Wall` implies [`-Wunticked-promoted-constructors`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wunticked-promoted-constructors). I'm wondering why this warning is important; if I am allowed to write in an unticked style in the default syntax, what's the harm?

Most of the dependently typed code I've written has been in Idris (and a little in Agda) and so I'm used to a unified namespace of types and values. As such it feels natural to me to write in an unticked style. However, if there is potential harm in it, I will add the ticks. But I don't want to do that without understanding why.

So for example, if I have a data type like this:

```
data HasDefault = IsDefaulted | NotDefaulted
```

that is used in a function signature like this:

```
setDefault :: a -> T p NotDefaulted a -> T p IsDefaulted a
```

then I get a warning like this (with `-Werror` also set):

```
C:\path-to-my-lib\src\Lib.hs:103:46: error: [-Wunticked-promoted-constructors, -Werror=unticked-promoted-constructors]
    Unticked promoted constructor: `IsDefaulted'.
    Use 'IsDefaulted instead of `IsDefaulted'.
    |
103 | setDefault :: a -> T p NotDefaulted a -> T p IsDefaulted a
    |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Should I worry about this, and make sure to be diligent about the ticking lifted constructors? Or should I turn the warning off?

Comment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#distinguishing-between-types-and-constructors "*As a convenience, GHC allows you to omit the quote mark when the name is unambiguous. However, our experience has shown that the quote mark helps to make code more readable and less error-prone.*"

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for pointing that out. I would be curious to hear more detail on "more readable and less error-prone" (is readability here a matter of background---more readable for Haskellers, but perhaps not more so for Idris folks, etc? what kind of errors can occur? etc.)

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately that is all I was able to find in the manual.

Comment: Given `data Proxy (t :: k)` and `newtype Identity a = Identity a`, `Proxy Identity` and `Proxy 'Identity` aren't the same type. I find using `'` uniformly even when unambiguous makes it easier for me to read data kinds.

Comment: I guess it's also due to `data T = T` being legal in Haskell, unlike Agda. Hence we need to disambiguate between `F T` and `F 'T` when `F` is polykinded and can accept both `T :: *` and `'T :: T`.